# Create Solr core/collection in Java/Solrj

Tags: java, solr

Can I create Solr collection in using Solrj? I am using Solr 5 and Solr 6. 
There are some examples using earlier Solr versions. I have not found document/example of doing this in Solr 5/6.

I found one way of doing this is to copy an existing Solr collection and modify core.properties. But this approach requires restart Solr.